# Scala List with mixed type mismatch errors

Tags: scala

Can I use scala list with different data types? I tried to create a projList that hardcodes different values but I got the mismatch errors. I don't know how to convert Any to Long, Timestamp, and Boolean below. Any ideas? Please advise. Thanks!!

```
val cTime: Timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())
val projList = List("test", 102, cTime, true)
Project(projList(0), projList(1), projList(2), projList(3))

type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Any
[error]  required: Long
[error]  Project(1, projList(0).toString, projList(1), projList(2), projList(3))
```

Comment: Type `Any` is the compiler's way of saying, "I don't know what the original data type is anymore. From here on you are on your own." Avoid type `Any` whenever possible (and it _is_ almost always possible).

Comment: Review [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48048115/list-and-tuples-in-scala), and the answers, for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The list you have created is `List[Any]`. You can use a `Tuple4` containing 4 types:

```
val projParams = ("test", 102, cTime, true)
Project(projParams._1, projParams._2, projParams._3, projParams._4)
```

By why bother?

```
Project("test", 102, cTime, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using a List[Any], looks like a complete anti-pattern, but if you really need to, then you can cast the variables like this:

```
Project(projList(0).asInstanceOf[String], 
  projList(1).asInstanceOf[Long], 
  projList(2).asInstanceOf[Timestamp], 
  projList(3).asInstanceOf[Boolean])
```

Note that 120 is an Integer and will fail to parse as Long, you should use 120L