# How do I match Regex Pattern on List to filter out decimal elements in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I am wondering without creating a function, how can I filter out numbers from a list with both numbers and strings:

```
val a = sc.parallelize(List(“cat”,“horse”,4.0,3.5,2,“dog”))
```

I believe my question indeed is looking for how to use regex in Scala to find out matched pattern

----Updated on 20180302 11pm EST:
Thanks to @Nyavro which is the closest answer, I slightly modified as below:

```
val doubles = a.collect {
  case v: Double => v
  case v: Int => v
}
```

Now I get:

> res10: Array[Double] = Array(4.0, 3.5, 2.0)

Just be curious, can types be mixed in a collect result in Scala?

Thanks to all replies.

Comment: If these things are numbers, then they *aren't even Strings*. What do you want to do with regex here?

Comment: Don't mix types in a `List()`. That way lies madness.

Comment: @jwvh While I agree 100% with that statement, I wouldn't blame it on the OP. As it seems, instead of trying to come up with patterns that allow us to type (or otherwise "schematize") everything consistently back to front, everyone has agreed to just pulverize all the interesting interconnections between the entities in the real world, dump everything in rectangular stringly-typed comma separated text files and then to make `try { toInt }` and `isInstanceOf`-checks trying to recover some sanity from the `List[Any]`-madness all day long...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter for elements of type `Int` and `Double`, and to retain their respective types, you might try this.

```
a.flatMap {
  case v: Int => Some(v)
  case v: Double => Some(v)
  case _ => None
}
//res0: List[AnyVal] = List(4.0, 3.5, 2)
```

To help understand why this is a really bad idea, read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48048115/list-and-tuples-in-scala), and its answers.

Answer (score 2):

Use collect:

```
val doubles = a.collect {
  case v: Double => v
}
```

Comment: Thank you, almost there, it is missing "2" in the result. please see my updated OP

Answer (score -1):

You can use `isInstanceOf` to check whether an element of your list is a string.

```
val l = List("cat","horse",4.0,3.5,2,"dog")
l.filter(_.isInstanceOf[String])
>> List[Any] = List(cat, horse, dog)
```

Regex is (largely) irrelevant here because you do not have strings, you have a `List[Any]` that you're turning into an `RDD[Any]`. (The RDD is largely irrelevant here, too, except RDDs have no `filterNot` and Lists do--I can't tell if you want to keep the strings or drop the strings.)

Note also that `filter` takes a function as an argument--having some function here is inescapable, even if it's anonymous, as it is in my example.

I have an inkling, though, that I've given an answer to the opposite of what you're asking, and you have an `RDD[String]` that you want to convert to `RDD[Double]`, throwing away the strings that don't convert. In that case, I would try to convert the strings to doubles, wrapping that in a `Try` and check for success, using the result to filter:

```
def isDouble(s: String) = Try(s.toDouble).isSuccess
```

Comment: Thank you hoyland, and sorry my question seems not clear to you, yes I need to get only the three decimal in the result: 4.0, 3.5, 2; btw: the def isDouble returns error here on my side

Comment: @Choix is the error about `Try` not being found? If so, you need to import `util.Try`.